# Create Dynamic database and run existing migrations laravel

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I've an application in that Admin can create new users and after created new user I want to create separate databases for each user created, and I've some migrations(tables) in the user application. So After creating new database I'm not able to run the users migration in new database.

```
 DB::statement('create database ' .$dbName ); // with this I'm creating new db and after this I've some command like this:
 Artisan::call('migrate', ['--database' => $new_connection]);*
```

It's creating database but it's not creating any migrations in this database. please help me in this.

Example Code:

```
if (DB::statement('create database ' . $dbName) == true) {
    $new_connection = 'new';
    $nc = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::set('database.connec‌​tions.' . $new_connect‌​ion, [
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => $dbName,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
    ]);
    Artisan::call('migrate', ['--database' => $nc]);
} else {
    return 'db already exists!';
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create user specific databases instead of just using referencing `user_id` on related tables?

Comment: I want the functionality like this 
https://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly
So I'm implementing with separate database for each user.

Comment: To achieve that you don't need to have multiple databases, in fact you'll probably run in to a few issues doing this! IMO, you will be much better off just using relationships between your tables. I'm not saying this to be condescending  at all but do you know about `one-to-one`, `one-to-many`, and/or `many-to-many` relationships with database design.

Comment: yes, I know the relationships, but there are some dynamic fields in some tables, so, to show the tables with dynamic fields of each user created, I've to create individual databases for each user. got it, right??

Comment: Ok, I've got it!!! Can you at least show the rest of your code i.e. how you're setting up the connection etc?

Comment: sample code
`if(DB::statement('create database ' .$dbName)==true){
          
            $new_connection='new';
            $nc=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::set('database.connections.'.$new_connection, array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'database' => $dbName,
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
            ));

            Artisan::call('migrate', ['--database' => $nc]);
        }
        else
            return 'db already exists!';
}`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Config::set()` doesn't return anything.

The reason your code is working is because you're not passing the name of the connection which in your example is stored in `$new_connection`.

Change you're artisan command to be:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', ['--database' => $new_connection]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did this answer your question, @Chiru?